# Google API not recognized by IDE/Maven

Tags: java, maven, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I'm using the google API for OAuth token verification server-side. The imports are:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
```

And in my Maven `pom.xml` dependencies section:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I'm getting

> Cannot resolve symbol "googleapis"

When I check what packages are in `com.google.api.client`, I don't see `googleapis` either. However, these imports were taken straight from the example [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

Comment: You're getting that error on a code location that you didn't include here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out - I just had to add the Google API client as well as the OAuth client. Here's what the dependencies look like in the `pom.xml`.

```
<!-- verify oauth tokens -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
```